# Show different navbar items on collapse (ngx-bootstrap)

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

With ngx-bootstrap, is it possible to show different navbar bootstrap items depending on whether the navbar is collapsed or not?

I tried to do this by making a div for collapsed and !collapsed.  Unfortunately, both show when !collapsed.

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-startup-proj-ddztm4

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand"
     href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target=".navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed"
          (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- show only when not collapsed -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarSupportedContent"
       [ngClass]="{'hide': isCollapsed}">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link"
           href="#">Link One - full screen</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link"
           href="#">Link Two - full screen</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- show only when collapsed -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarSupportedContent"
  [ngClass]="{'show': !isCollapsed}">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link"
            href="#">Link Two - collapsed</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-success"
            href="#">Link Three - collapsed</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

TS:

```
 isCollapsed = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible if you add `[style.display]="isCollapsed?'inherit':'none'"` into `<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"`:

```
<!-- show only when not collapsed -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarSupportedContent"
[ngClass]="{'hide': isCollapsed}">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <!-- rest of code .... -->
</div>
<!-- show only when collapsed -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarSupportedContent"
[ngClass]="{'show': !isCollapsed}">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" [style.display]="isCollapsed?'inherit':'none'">
  <!-- rest of code .... -->
</div>
```

### Update:

To make it responsive you can use [@media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)(example in [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)):

```
@media (max-width: 576px){
   ul.collapse{
      display:none !important;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 576px){
   ul.full{
      display:none !important;
   }
}
```

in `css` then add the following `ul` classes:

```
<!-- show only when not collapsed -->
`<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto collapse">`

<!-- show only when collapsed -->
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto full" [style.display]="isCollapsed?'inherit':'none'">
```

Example on **[Stackblitz Fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-startup-proj-gu6sdf?file=app/nav/nav.component.html)**

Comment: Do you have any fiddle / snippet?

Comment: I'll put one together.  Even in the stackblitz  that you just sent, both items are showing when the navigation is full.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Here's a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-startup-proj-ddztm4

Comment: Thanks.  Closer, but has 2 issues:  1) the first link one/two show up in the collapsed view  2) If you click the toggle, then expand the screen to full view, all 4 links show up in the navbar...so it's not responding to screen resizing so much as the toggle.  So the menu really isn't changing based on screen size...

Comment: Glad to help :) Good luck next.